# Exporting gridview data to .csv using save file dialog

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, csv, gridview

Im trying to export data from gridview to .csv and saving it using save file dialog, but when i press the button, nothing happens. Gridview works correctly, here is the code:

```
 public struct DataParameters
    {
        public List<Currency> currency;
        public string Filename;

    }

    public static DataParameters dataParameters;
```

On button click - open file dialog export file to csv and save it

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog() { Filter = "CSV 
files (*.csv)|*.csv|All files (*.*)|*.*" ,
            ValidateNames = true, InitialDirectory = @"C:\",
            RestoreDirectory = true, CheckFileExists = true, CheckPathExists 
= true, DefaultExt = "csv" }) {
            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                dataParameters.currency = GridView1.DataSource as 
List<Currency>;
                dataParameters.Filename = sfd.FileName;
            }
        }

        List<Currency> currencies = dataParameters.currency;
        string filename = dataParameters.Filename;
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(filename, 
  FileMode.Create), Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (Currency c in currencies)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(string.Format($"{c.Drzava} {c.Sifra_valute} { 
{c.Valuta} {c.Jedinica} {c.Kupovni_tecaj} {c.Srednji_tecaj} 
{c.Prodajni_tecaj}"));
            }
            sw.Write(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Nothing happens when i press the button

Comment: dataParameters.currency = GridView1.DataSource as 
List<Currency>;  <--- here im trying to assign gridview's data to list

Comment: button is assigned, tried with messagebox.show

Comment: When you say "Nothing happens when i press the button" do you mean that you don't even see the file dialog or you mean that it doesn't write the file?

Comment: I don't see  the dialog